# htaccess not working in sub directory

Tags: .htaccess

My website is hosted in a sub directory (`http://example.com/folder`).

In root directory I forward `http://example.com` to `http://example.com/folder` where I have created a blog page and I rewrite URL like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-(.+)\.html$ \/folder\/blog\.php?title=$1&bid=$2 [L]
```

This is working but it affecting other folder URL means like `http://example.com/folder2` who will be redirected to my blog.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the directory or the file really exist and not apply the redirection with conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-(.+)\.html$ \/folder\/blog\.php?title=$1&bid=$2 [L]
```